# Как сделать сетку между картинками на всю ширину/ в css

Tags: html, css

Получается такая проблема, не знаю как сделать сетку картинкам при помощи бордер. На скрине эту сетку еле видно, но она есть. Она идёт вокруг каждого элемента картинки, но не в плотную, и проходит через весь сайт. Я пытался чё-то сделать но всё ни как.

```css
.brands {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.border {
    border-bottom: none;
    border: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 2px solid;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.border img {
    filter: grayscale(1);
    opacity: .3;
}

.team-speak, .team-ups, .team-allegro {
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 70px 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<section class="brands">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                     <div class="team-speak border">
                      <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/10/e469cf7179e2a2530a7472579cf7ea59-full.png" alt="">
                      <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/10/e469cf7179e2a2530a7472579cf7ea59-full.png" alt="">
                      <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/10/e469cf7179e2a2530a7472579cf7ea59-full.png" alt="">
                      <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/10/e469cf7179e2a2530a7472579cf7ea59-full.png" alt="">
                      <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/10/e469cf7179e2a2530a7472579cf7ea59-full.png" alt="">
                      <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/10/e469cf7179e2a2530a7472579cf7ea59-full.png" alt="">
                      <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/10/e469cf7179e2a2530a7472579cf7ea59-full.png" alt="">
                      </div>                                             
                        </div>
                    </div>
          </section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Коли вариантов пока нет, держи такой. Толи это что тебе нужо ?

```css
section{
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid  #dadada;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center; 
}

section div:first-child, section div:nth-child(2n+1) { 
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top: none;
}
section div:nth-child(2n) { 
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top: none;
}
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #dadada;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 40px;
}
img{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<section style="border: none;"><div> </div> 
 <div></div> 
 <div></div> 
 <div></div> 
</section>

<section>
  <div> <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/10/e469cf7179e2a2530a7472579cf7ea59-full.png" alt="">
  </div> 
  <div><img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/10/e469cf7179e2a2530a7472579cf7ea59-full.png" alt="">
  </div> 
  <div><img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/10/e469cf7179e2a2530a7472579cf7ea59-full.png" alt="">
  </div> 
  <div><img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/10/e469cf7179e2a2530a7472579cf7ea59-full.png" alt="">
  </div>
</section>

<section>
 <div></div> 
 <div></div> 
 <div></div> 
 <div></div>
</section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо